# difference between encapsulation and abstraction concepts

Tags: oop, encapsulation, abstraction

Can somebody explain to me the main differences between the principles of encapsulation and abstraction in objected-oriented programming (if possible with examples).

Comment: encapsulation means-hiding data e-g using getter and setter etc.
Abstraction means- hiding implementation using abstract class and interfaces etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sample:

```
// NO ABSTRACTION, NO ENCAPSULATION
const int catLegs = 4;
const int spiderLegs = 8;

Leg[] catLegs;
Leg[] spiderLegs;

void MakeCatRun(Distance b) { for (int i=0; i<catLegs; ++i) catLegs[i] += b; }
void MakeSpiderRun(Distance b) { for (int i=0; i<spiderLegs; ++i) spiderLegs[i] += b; }
```

Encapsulation:

```
// ENCAPSULATION
class Cat
{
    Leg[] legs;
    int nLegs;

    public void Run(Distance b) { for (int i=0; i < nLegs; ++i) leg[i] += b; }
}

class Spider
{
    Leg[] legs;
    int nLegs;

    public void Run(Distance b) { for (int i=0; i < nLegs; ++i) leg[i] += b; }
}
```

Abstraction:

```
 // ABSTRACTION
    class LivingBeing
    {
        Leg[] legs;
        int nLegs;

        public void Run(Distance b) { for (int i=0; i < nLegs; ++i) leg[i] += b; }
    }

    class Cat: LivingBeing       {        }

    class Spider: LivingBeing   {    }
```

Comment: From your example it seems that abstraction is nothing but - "moving out common properties into a different class"

Answer (score 5):

**Abstraction** is that quality that we just do not bother about unnecessary internal mechanisms (implementations) and can deal with a system/object, looking in to the essentialities.

*Eg: While applying brakes on a car you just don't care if it has got air-brake or hydraulic-brake. Abstraction comes in the form of a pedal-push here.*

**Encapsulation** is something that makes the above (abstraction) possible by packing (encapsulating) details of implementation within a container *(hiding away breaking mechanisms and tiny components from your eyesight or physical contact, in the above case)*.

**So, Encapsulation in effect provides Abstraction!**

If you look around, you can see it everywhere around you in real world. Also it is there in programming- If Someone provides you a class to Sort list of integers, you don't really need to bother about the sorting algorithm (bubble sort/Quick Sort) it uses, The abstraction makes it possible that you 'pass the list of integers' to the method; that is it.

```
 class Sorter
 {
  public List<Integer> Sort(List<Integer>)//Only this method is seen outside
  {
    String pattrenName=this.AdvancedPatternFinder();
    this.Advancedsorter(pattenName);
    //Return sorted list
  } 
  private String AdvancedPatternFinder(){}//NOT seen from outside
  private void Advancedsorter(String pattrenName){}//NOT seen from outside
 }
```

See the below animation to understand how a neat abstraction is provided by encapsulating internal details inside!

image courtesy:[this blog](http://objectorientedthought.blogspot.in/2015/09/abstraction-in-oop.html)

[image]

Comment: In the comment in code you have said `Only this method is seen outside`. How is this method given out to the external world. Is it through the source code or some documentation of the API's?

Comment: @LinuxPenseur it is marked as public, and hence visible outside the class, by convention

Answer (score 4):

Encapsulation means that object's internal state (data) can be modified only by its public methods (public interface):

```
class Encapsulated  {
  private int data;

  public int getData()  { return data; }
  public void setData(int d) { data = d; }
}
```

Abstraction means that you can abstract from concrete implementations, for example:

```
abstract class Container  {
  int getSize();
}

class LinkedList extends Container {
  int getSize() { /* return the size */ }
}

class Vector extends Container {
  int getSize()  { /* ... */ }
}
```

If you will be using the Container abstract class in all your code instead of Vector or LinkedList, you will be able to switch the concrete implementation of Container (Vector/LinkedList in this case) without changing any of your code, thus abstracting yourself from the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The two concepts are distinct, but closely related and are often found together.

Abstraction is hiding of non-essential details, usually termed implementation details. For example, to read data from a stream, most environments have the concept of an `InputStream`. It provides a ReadBytes() method to fetch more bytes from the stream. How it does this is abstracted away - it could be reading from a file, using the OS file APIs, or reading from a socket, from SSH or anything else that can be presented as a stream of bytes. The InputStream class is said to be an abstraction.

Each implementation of InputStream codes how the bytes are read. For example, a FileInputStream reads bytes from a file, and maintains the current offset into the file as a private data member. Code external to the class does not have free access to read or write this variable directly - doing so might lead to incorrect results, such as part of the stream being skipped, or re-read. This is especially important in multi-threaded scenarios, when changes to the variable needs to be carefully controlled. Instead of giving unfettered access, the class uses the `offset` internally (by declaring it `private`), and gives external code only indirect access, such as via a method `GetCurrentOffset()`, and methods `Seek(int offset)`. The offset variable is then encapsulated by the FileInputStream class.